# Power of 2 choices

Tags: probability, probability-theory

How can i change the proof for  Power of 2 choices to $d>2$ choices, where i want to show  that with probability $1-n^{-2}$, the max-load is $\log _{d} \log n+O(1)$ instead of $\log _{2} \log n+O(1)$.

For $\boldsymbol{m}$ balls into $\boldsymbol{n}$ bins i do know, with high prob. $1-n^{-10}$, the max-load of 2 -choice hash is $\log \log n+O\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)$ , How do i tackle the above problem.

Comment: "How can I change the proof ?" Which **proof** ? Do you mean its **formula**?

Comment: @JeanMarie It's official theorem proof, like this one: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/Randalgs11/lectures/lect0202.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference.